# What is Pen drain pine in basement?

Tags: basement, pipe, pump

I have two pipes going into sump. One is Radon and another is Pen drain. Can any one please explain what is Pen drain pipe. I couldn't get any info about this in internet.[image]

Comment: Are there any animal pens near the house?

Comment: I was wondering what the ?  until reading tester101 coment , now I  would look to see where the pipe goes. Probably a pen.+